# Reset the natbib option longnamesfirst at each chapter

Tags: citing, memoir, natbib

I am writing my thesis as a collection of papers and I want to have the full bibliography at the end of the thesis. As there is several references that are used in more than one chapter, I would like to "reset" the `longnamesfirst` option of the `natbib` package at each chapter. To illustrate here is a MWE.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{memoir}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[round,longnamesfirst]{natbib}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
    @ARTICLE{ahuja2002,
        author = {Ahuja, R.K. and Ergun, {\"O}. and Orlin, J.B. and Punnen, A.P.},
        title = {A survey of very large-scale neighborhood search techniques},
        journal = {Discrete Applied Mathematics},
        year = {2002},
        volume = {123},
        pages = {75--102},
        number = {1},
        publisher = {Elsevier}
    }
\end{filecontents}


\begin{document}
    \chapter{First chapter}
        \cite{ahuja2002}\\
    \chapter{Second chapter}
        \cite{ahuja2002} $\leftarrow$ That guy should be ``longnamesfirst'' as well!
    \bibliographystyle{plainnat}
    \bibliography{\jobname} 
\end{document}
```

I use the `memoir` document class for the thesis, so the question is tagged [memoir](/questions/tagged/memoir) as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is one way of doing it. Natbib does it thing by defining a special macro the first time each key is cited. Subsequent citations check for this macro. We thus need two things: (1) to undefine these macros at the start of each chapter and (2) know a list of all the possible keys.

The later is gathered via knowing that the cited keys are in the aux file, so we overload `\bibcite` to also add the keys to a global list. That list is then looped through at the start of each chapter. (after the title)

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{memoir}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[round,longnamesfirst]{natbib}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
    @ARTICLE{ahuja2002,
        author = {Ahuja, R.K. and Ergun, {\"O}. and Orlin, J.B. and Punnen, A.P.},
        title = {A survey of very large-scale neighborhood search techniques},
        journal = {Discrete Applied Mathematics},
        year = {2002},
        volume = {123},
        pages = {75--102},
        number = {1},
        publisher = {Elsevier}
    }
\end{filecontents}

%\bibcite{ahuja2002}{{1}{2002}{{Ahuja et~al.}}{{Ahuja, Ergun, Orlin,
%and Punnen}}}
\let\bibitemkeylist\relax
\AtEndPreamble{
  \let\normalbibcite\bibcite
  \renewcommand\bibcite[2]{%
    \listgadd{\bibitemkeylist}{#1}
    \normalbibcite{#1}{#2}%
  }
}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\RESETHANDLER[1]{\global\cslet{bv@#1\@extra@b@citeb}\relax}
\newcommand\RESET{
  \forlistloop\RESETHANDLER\bibitemkeylist
}

\renewcommand\memendofchapterhook{\RESET}

\makeatother
\usepackage{hyperref}



\begin{document}
    \chapter{First chapter}
    First: \cite{ahuja2002}

    Second: \cite{ahuja2002}




    \chapter{Second chapter}

    First: \cite{ahuja2002}

    Second: \cite{ahuja2002}

    \bibliographystyle{plainnat}
    \bibliography{\jobname} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Nice solution! It works exactly as I hoped it would!

Comment: Remember to accepted it it worked. I've tested it with `hyperref` and it should work with that as well